# Ruby file output on Unix Instance

Tags: ruby, windows, file, unix, io

I am in the middle of a project which requires me to filter out words from a relatively large text file, i.e. 5 million lines.  I wrote a quick ruby script which worked fine in a windows environment, using Ruby 2.0.0.  The program is supposed to take in a text file and output another text file filtering out the blacklisted words.  When I ported it to the unix instance, on AWS, the script did not write text to the output file.  Is there something special I need to do in Ruby/Unix environment as far are file IO that I don't have to do in a Ruby/Windows setting?

My code is below:

```
# Ruby Script to remove stop words make sure all included
# words are in the frequency list
# Date 11/19/14 (PTC)

# Open linux.words and place in an array
wordList = []
lineList = []
stopWords = []
goodLineList = []

File.open('freqList.txt') do |f|
  f.lines.each do |line|
    wordList << line.downcase.gsub(/\n/, "")
    # puts line.downcase
  end
end

File.open('stop_words.txt') do |f|
  f.lines.each do |line|
    stopWords << line.downcase
    # puts line.downcase
  end
end

# read in sample to object
File.open('temp.txt') do |f|
  f.lines.each do |line|
    lineList << line.downcase
  end
end


# for each line, split then if only save actual words to new object

lineList.each do |line|
  s = ""
  splitLine = line.split(" ")
  splitLine.each do |token|
    if wordList.include? token and !stopWords.include? token
      s = s + token + " "
    end
  end

  goodLineList << s

end  # line in list

# Write object to new file
cleanedFile = File.open("cleanData.txt", "w")
count = 1 
goodLineList.each do |line|
  cleanedFile.puts line
  puts "Line: " + count.to_s + line
  count = count + 1`enter code here`
end
cleanedFile.close

puts "finished"
```

Comment: The line endings in Windows (DOS) are different than in UNIX, so that might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Any suggestions as a replacement for "cleanFile.puts line".  All it is pushing to the file is one NULL byte.

Comment: I am not familiar with Ruby (although it is in my wish list), so I don't know. What I suggest you is to also check `grep` together with `-f`, which can work for simple cases when you have patterns in a file and you want to grep out them. See for example [Reading grep patterns from a file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83260/reading-grep-patterns-from-a-file).

Comment: BTW, ruby is good for on the fly stuff; no so much in production.

Comment: Interesting! Also, you can provide some sample input and desired output, maybe this way I can help further on the UNIX aspect.

Comment: Ruby is just fine for production. Where are you getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `chomp` it is portable across operating systems:

```
f.lines.each do |line|
  wordList << line.chomp.downcase
end
```

Or:

```
wordList = f.lines.map {|line| line.chomp.downcase}
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html

Your actual problem might be here:

```
count = count + 1`enter code here`
```

The `` cause execution of the command "enter code here" and `enter` isn't, as far as I know, a valid unix command.